# SyncAdapterのonPerformSync()の引数ContentProviderClientについて

Tags: android

[Creating a Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)を始め、`SyncAdapter`について解説している記事では、`AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`のサブクラスのコンストラクタで、

```
public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
  super(context, autoInitialize);
  mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
}
```

`ContentResolver`を取得してプライベートなメンバ変数として保持するのがセオリーとしていることが多いです。

しかし、`onPerformSync()`の呼び出しを見ると、

```
provider = mContext.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(mAuthority);
if (provider != null) {
  AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.this.onPerformSync(mAccount, mExtras, mAuthority, provider, syncResult);
} else {
  syncResult.databaseError = true;
}
```

このタイミングで`ContentResolver`を取得し、さらに`ContentProviderClient`を獲得して`onPerformSync()`の引数に渡してくれます。コンストラクタで`ContentResolver`を保持するより、引数`provider`を利用して`ContentProvider`を操作した方が効率的なように思えます。

引数`provider`を利用しないのには、何か意味があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

通常は `ContentProviderClient` を使えば良いです。

リンク先のコードのコメント(英語)にも書いてあるとおり、
`ContextResolver` は **必要ならば取る** べきものです。

```
/*
 * If your app uses a content resolver, get an instance of it
 * from the incoming Context
 */
mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
```

ですから、考えるべきなのは「`ContentProviderClient` を利用しない意味」ではなく「`ContentResolver` を利用する意味」、すなわち「どういう時に`ContentResolver` を使うのか」です。

この意味にはいくつか考えられるでしょうけれども、
そのうちの1つは両者の違いを考えれば明らかです。
`ContentProviderClient` は1つの `ContentProvider` へ高速にアクセスできるのに対し、
`ContentResolver` は遅くなるものの全ての `ContentProvider` へアクセスできます。
同期時に複数の `ContentProvier` からのデータが必要な場合には、
`ContentResolver` が必要になるのです。